# How to show organized data from rails helper content tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

> How to show organized data from rails helper content tag?

Like below is my helper method and I want to show all categories name grouped by a parent, and that is `ul` `li` if you can please see below method I think you will understand that code & what do I want. That method outputted the data but not with `ul` `li`

The helper method

```
def category
    parent_categories = Category.select(:id, :name, :parent).group_by(&:parent)
    parent_categories.each do |parent, childs|
        content_tag(:div) do 
            content_tag(:h1, parent)
        end +
        content_tag(:ul) do 
            childs.each do |child|
                content_tag(:li, child.name)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

the output of `<%= category %>`

```
{"Technology"=>[#<Category id: 1, name: "Programming", parent: "Technology">, #<Category id: 3, name: "Ruby on Rails", parent: "Technology">, #<Category id: 9, name: "Full Time", parent: "Technology">, #<Category id: 14, name: "Business Opportunities", parent: "Technology">, #<Category id: 15, name: "Contract & Freelance", parent: "Technology">, #<Category id: 18, name: "Engineering", parent: "Technology">, #<Category id: 25, name: "IT", parent: "Technology">], 

"Education"=>[#<Category id: 5, name: "Industry", parent: "Education">, #<Category id: 6, name: "Education", parent: "Education">, #<Category id: 7, name: "Education & Industry", parent: "Education">, #<Category id: 16, name: "Customer Service", parent: "Education">, #<Category id: 17, name: "Diversity Opportunities", parent: "Education">],

"Other"=>[#<Category id: 8, name: "Part Time", parent: "Other">, #<Category id: 12, name: "Admin & Clerical", parent: "Other">]}
```

the schema.rb

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "parent"
end
```

That was my done works.

After the example is what do I want like

**Technology** (Parent)

- Programming
- Ruby on Rails
- Ruby
- ReactJS

**Education** (Parent)

- Office
- Teacher
- Physics

**Other** (Parent)

- Clinical
- Helth
- etc...

Please help out me to done this works.

Thanks

Comment: try `.collect` instead of `each`

Comment: Are you wanting categories to reference another category as a parent or just predefined strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ERB in your helper but it is not an html.erb file so you don't get the tags you are trying to create. Why not just use the hash you've produced and then I think what you are looking for is something like:

The helper method:

```
def category
  Category.select(:id, :name, :parent).group_by(&:parent)
end
```

And in your view file (.html.erb) do something like:

```
  <% category.each do |cat, list| %>
    <div class="category">
      <b> <%= cat %> </b>
      <ul>
        <% list.each do |item| %>
          <li> <%= item.name %> </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
  <% end %>
```

OK, you can do it the way you are proposing using the `concat` method according to the documentation:

```
def category
    parent_categories = Category.select(:id, :name, :parent).group_by(&:parent)
    parent_categories.each do |parent, childs|
        concat content_tag(:div) do 
           concat content_tag(:h1, parent)
        end 
       concat content_tag(:ul) do 
            childs.each do |child|
               concat content_tag(:li, child.name)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry! I want to show full content from helper method, can you help out please

Comment: I did that. A helper method is just plain Ruby that returns a value. You can't use the tag methods in the helper. Have you tried what I wrote?

Comment: It was my actual code, I want to done this whole things in one helper method

Comment: That's not what the helper methods are for. That is why you aren't getting any tags. The only thing the helper method returns is the value of 'parent_categories'

Comment: I added another way of doing it. According to the docs at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat you can use the `concat` method in helper methods. I think it's a bit of a hack, and prefer to use eRuby in ERB files, but to each their own.